# Обособление сравнительного оборота

Tags: пунктуация, как, сравнительный-оборот

Нужна ли запятая в следующем предложении:

**Тогда Рябинин сделал вывод, необходимый каждому следователю(,) как скальпель хирургу: следствие держится на совести.**

Я бы запятую не ставил, хотя в книге запятая стоит. По-моему, оборот сей имеет тесную смысловую связь.

Comment: Все это предложение, я бы сказал, не выдерживает критики с литературной точки зрения. Каждому следователю необходим ... вывод(?!). Вывод необходим следователю как скальпель хирургу (?!)

Comment: Предложение взято из повести С.В.Родионова"Криминальный талант",по которой был снят одноименный фильм.

Comment: Фильм я люблю. Я сделал вывод, необходимый каждому читателю: современные повести держатся на сюжете (а не на хорошем литературном стиле) :)))

Comment: Петр, посмотрите ответы на вопросы, помеченные метками "как" и "сравнительный-оборот", и попробуйте сделать вывод самостоятельно. Если возникнут сомнения - изложите их в вопросе.

Comment: Я бы запятую не ставил,хотя в книге запятая стоит.

Comment: Почему не ставил бы? Попробуйте аргументировать. В основном сравнительные обороты с "как" обособляются. Можете указать причину, по которой этого не надо делать?

Comment: Почему?По-моему,оборот сей имеет тесную смысловую связь.

Comment: Петр, я добавил эти Ваши слова в вопрос (вопрос должен по возможности включать рассуждения автора вопроса). Прошу прощения за вторжение на Вашу территорию. Если Вы не согласны - всегда можете что-то удалить/исправить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Тогда Рябинин сделал вывод, необходимый каждому следователю**, **как скальпель** (необходим) **хирургу: следствие держится на совести.**

Это **неполное сравнительное придаточное** с пропущенным сказуемым, поэтому ставится запятая.

Пример:Существование его заключено в эту тесную програм­му, как яйцо в скорлупу. 
Источник: [ПРИДАТОЧНЫЕ СРАВНИТЕЛЬНЫЕ | lingvotech.com](http://lingvotech.com/pridatochnie_sravnitelnie)